# What are the odds for detecting radio transmissions from an other civilisation .. Drakes equation with twist

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Supposing there is someone out there trying to contact us, what are the odds that we could receive the signal?

What I'm driving at is that Drake's equation tries to estimate the likelihood of intelligent live in the universe, but it does not account for the likelihood of us being able to detect it, which to my lay mind would appear to be the main reason to Fermi's question "Where is everybody?"

Suppose a civilisation would be willing to sacrifice the power output a nuclear power plant (say 1 Tera Watt) just to reach out, how far could that be detected?

Using a directional antenna to send/receive the signal would limit the space we can cover at any one time but increase signal strength / reception sensitivity but with a given long enough time I expect we could cover (both sending and receiving) the whole of space.  So I guess we have have a time limit for this experiment, I would expect any civilisation would stop wasting resource after a period of time.

So assume 50 years or a few service lifetimes of the afore mentioned nuclear power station.

Would be nice to get some speculative figures for the distances we can reach and the odds of someone hearing us.

In the movie first contact a remote civilisation could receive Berlin Olympics TV broadcasts, to me that seems highly unlikely for anything but a very small portion of our own galaxy, let alone universe.

Comment: In 50 years you reach 50 light years. Directional radar pulses would be detectable to thousands of light years.

Answer (score 0):

Given speed limit $c$, in 50 years of constant operation of sending radio or other signals into outer space,- we could scan 50 Ly radius sphere.

As about likelihood of signal detection. We can't detect everything. Every creature which sends signals must be sure that at least:

1. **Target planet atmosphere will not absorb transmitted signal.**

Again, there can be many types of atmosphere, but *Earth-like* planet atmosphere will be transparent to the radio wavelength range about $[5cm-10m]$.
[image]

Of course, we or other civilization could build SETI radio telescopes in the orbit for widening available signal range, but given high cost of such projects (consider [James Webb Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) with total cost of 10 billion USD. Who will spend such money for controversial goals such as SETI ? According to Occam's razor extraterrestrials should be thinking the same)

2. **Transmitted signal is easily distinguishable from cosmic natural noise**

So to say there are a lot of natural signal emitting sources like neutron stars, quasars, blazars, supernovas, RRAT, Star forming regions, Cosmic Microwave background and [whatnot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_radio_source).

Hence, we have to have some region in the wavelengths which would be *free of natural cosmic noises*, so that we will not have a headache for thinking about various algorithms how to filter background noise out. And it's even may not be doable at all, because when every signal would be mixed-up,- we would not even know what to look for.

Hopefully, there is a such quiet radio window called [water hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hole_(radio)). It is about in the wavelength range of $[18cm-21cm]$. This is because in the interstellar medium there's a lot of $HO,~H$ gases which have absorption peak in the mentioned window. They absorbs natural radio source frequencies in that range pretty well, leaving cosmos relatively quiet in this window. That is why SETI search is based on $21~cm$ radio waves. Again, according to Occam's razor extraterrestrials should be thinking the same, i.e. how to make signal detection more easy, not more hard procedure for others.

Comment: The image shows the [water hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hole_(radio)).

Comment: My given image represents Earth atmospheric opacity chart for EM spectrum. Transparency window is at $[5cm-10m]$, but water hole is a lot more narrow,- at $[18cm-21cm]$. I don't see it there depicted.

Comment: Unless you had in mind depicted radio telescope placement on logarithmic $x$ scale. Then can be.